# Create Krakenjs app with yeoman

Tags: node.js, bower, kraken.js

I want to create a Krakenjs app whit the next command: `yo kraken` , but thw console give me the next error:

Stack trace:

```
Error: EACCES, open '/home/erik/.cache/bower/packages/64c3d861bd88c012885cd73d2f0e6a53-2.1.14.lock'

Console trace: Trace
    at StandardRenderer.error (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/renderers/StandardRenderer.js:72:17)
    at Logger.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower:110:22)
    at Logger.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Logger.emit (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-logger/lib/Logger.js:29:39)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/commands/index.js:40:20
    at _rejected (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:797:24)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:823:30
    at Promise.when (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:1035:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:741:41)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
```

System info:
Bower version: 1.3.9
Node version: 0.10.30
OS: Linux 3.13.0-32-generic x64

Comment: It looks like `bower` either didn't exit cleanly or another process is trying to use it.  I would try to clear your bower cache and start over.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably got items in `~/.cache/` owned by root. This happens when you run `bower` with sudo. You shouldn't need to do that.

Fix the permissions -- probably `sudo chown -R youruser ~/.cache/`